# How to change the wait() - Method of a Semaphore to include a boolean

Tags: c, semaphore

" If a critical area is locked, a call to wait usually causes a process to stall until the semaphore is allowed to pass (that is, until another process has issued a signal). However, there are also implementations of a semaphore that has a second Boolean parameter called "blocking" when calling the wait -Method.

If the blocking parameter is set to 'false', the call to wait doesn't block - the calling process receives instead a return value.

This return value is 'false' if the semaphore can not currently be passed, otherwise 'true'. Receive a process the return value 'true', it passed the semaphore, ergo wait is executed. "

I've written the code, but I'm really not sure how to implement the 'blocking' part of it. Especially how to give a process a return value. Some help with that would be really appreciated.

The code is in C-ish pseudocode.

```
struct semaphore {
 int value;
 list waiting_processes;
 boolean lock;
} 

wait(semaphore s, boolean blocking):
while (TestAndSet(s.lock))
      {noop;}
s.value = s.value - 1;
if (s.value < 0 && blocking == TRUE) {
    s.waiting_processes.add(get_pid());
    s.lock = FALSE;
    block();
} 
else { 
    s.lock = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: the function: `wait()` has nothing to do with a semaphore.  Rather the function: `wait() is for a parent process to 'pause' until a child process changes state (usually by exiting the child process)

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of `sem_wait()`  `sem_post()` `sem_open()` `sem_init()` and `sem_destroy()`